# Error: "cannot invoke initializer" for function to be executed on Watch OS only

Tags: swift, watchkit, init

I declared a failable initializer in my 'HealthKitService' which is, as the name says, a utility class for HealthKit. The problem is that certain HealthKit classes such as *HKWorkoutSession*, are available for Watch OS only, so I had to use a preprocessor directive to make a function available for Watch OS only:

```
#if TARGET_OS_WATCH
init?(activity:String) {
    // Here I initialize my HKWorkoutSession object
}
#endif
```

But if I call this initializer from the WatchKit extension app, this way:

```
if let service = HealthKitService(activity: activity) {
    // Do something with it
}
```

I receive this error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'HealthKitService' with an argument list of type '(activity: String)'

**PS:** The deployment target is Watch OS 3.2, Swift version: 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `#if os(watchOS)` instead of `#if TARGET_OS_WATCH`.